# Java File Errors Because of \

Tags: java

I have tried using System.getenv("APPDATA"), which returns \ between folders. FileOutPutStream does not handle these, so how can I convert the \'s to /'s?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you need to use a `\`, write two: `\\`. In other words: you need to escape it because the `\` character is itself the escaping character, and it needs to be escaped, too!

Alternatively, for file paths you could use instead a single `/`, it doesn't matter in which platform you're in (Windows, Linux, mac, etc.) it will work.

Back to your question: it's a bit weird that this is happening, the string returned by `getenv` surely is already escaping the `\` character. Let's try using the [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File%29) that takes a `File` instead:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(System.getenv("APPDATA")));
```

Comment: If you really want to use `/`, then simply do this:  `System.getenv("APPDATA").replace('\', '/')`

Comment: Thanks! I will use this for my program.

Answer (score 0):

```
File f = new File(System.getenv("APPDATA"));
System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

Then you can construct a new FileOutputStream(f);